# Upgrade From Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5 causing AccessViolationException

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, access-violation, silverlight-5.0

We have upgraded our project from Silverlight 4 to Silverlight 5 and now we are experiencing 
`AccessViolationException` from time to time in different places in the code, this exception is also causing the browser to crash.

Is there any guideline how to prevent this from happening?

I am adding the stack trace where the `AccessViolationException` was popped:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(MS.Internal.IManagedPeerBase obj, System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, string s) + 0x6f bytes
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(MS.Internal.IManagedPeerBase doh, System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, object obj) + 0x2ce bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetObjectValueToCore(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) + 0xd6 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, object newValue) + 0x35 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation) + 0xe6 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RefreshExpression(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x47 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SendDataToTarget() + 0xff bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.SourceAcquired() + 0x5f bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.BreakOnSharedType.AnonymousMethod__3() + 0x14 bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x6b bytes
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(object[] args) + 0xb bytes
BindingDebugging!TextPropertyPanelxaml_5.BindingOperation(object BindingState) + 0x30 bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.BreakOnSharedType(System.Type emittedType, System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingDebugState debugState, int bindingNumber, int line, int column, System.Action callback) + 0xd5 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Binding.EnsureBreakPoint(System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingDebugState debugState, System.Action callback, bool canDelay) + 0x1ff bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.System.Windows.IDataContextChangedListener.OnDataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0xa4 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0xc bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0x1e bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0x26 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0xcb bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0x32 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.NotifyDataContextChanged(System.Windows.DataContextChangedEventArgs e) + 0xcb bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x47 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object oldValue, object newValue) + 0x5e bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation) + 0xf3 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, bool allowReadOnlySet, bool isBindingInStyleSetter) + 0x248 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.DataContext.set(object value) + 0x28 bytes
ContentManagerSilverlight!ContentManagerSilverlight.TextPropertyPanel.set_ItemDetails(ContentManagerClientTypes.ServiceLibrary.ItemDetails value) Line 132 + 0xd bytes
ContentManagerSilverlight!ContentManagerSilverlight.PropertiesPanelControl.SetPanelsVisability(ContentManagerClientTypes.ServiceLibrary.ItemDetails p_item) Line 78 + 0x1f bytes
ContentManagerSilverlight!ContentManagerSilverlight.PropertiesPanelControl.HandleEvents(Object p_sender, String p_propertyName, Object p_propertyValue) Line 130 + 0x35 bytes
ContentManagerClientTypes!ContentManagerClientTypes.Messenger.Send(Object p_sender, String p_propertyName, Object p_propertyValue) Line 34 + 0x55 bytes
ContentManagerSilverlight!ContentManagerSilverlight.LibraryViewModel.set_SelectedItemDetails(ContentManagerClientTypes.ServiceLibrary.ItemDetails value) Line 181 + 0x25 bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.CLRPropertyListener.Value.set(object value) + 0x23 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.PropertyAccessPathStep.Value.set(object value) + 0xe bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateValue() + 0x692 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.BreakOnSharedType.AnonymousMethod__3() + 0x14 bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(object[] args) + 0x6b bytes
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(object[] args) + 0xb bytes
BindingDebugging!LibraryThumbViewxaml.BindingOperation(object BindingState) + 0x30 bytes
[Native to Managed Transition]
[Managed to Native Transition]
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingBreakPoint.BreakOnSharedType(System.Type emittedType, System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingDebugState debugState, int bindingNumber, int line, int column, System.Action callback) + 0xd5 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.Binding.EnsureBreakPoint(System.Windows.Data.Debugging.BindingDebugState debugState, System.Action callback, bool canDelay) + 0x1ff bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateValueEnsureBreak() + 0x53 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.UpdateValueIfNecessary() + 0x68 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TargetPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x2b bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x16 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x54 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp) + 0x13 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object oldValue, object newValue) + 0x5e bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty property, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, System.Windows.DependencyObject.ValueOperation operation) + 0xf3 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, bool allowReadOnlySet, bool isBindingInStyleSetter) + 0x1c9 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.UpdatePublicSelectionProperties(int oldSelectedIndex, int newSelectedIndex, object oldSelectedItem, object newSelectedItem) + 0xca bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End() + 0x172 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.SelectJustThisItem(int oldIndex, int newIndex) + 0x170 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.MakeSingleSelection(int index) + 0x3e bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.HandleItemSelection(System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem item, bool isMouseSelection) + 0x7a bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnListBoxItemClicked(System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem item) + 0x7 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.ListBoxItem.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) + 0x54 bytes
System.Windows.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Controls.Control ctrl, System.EventArgs e) + 0x38 bytes
System.Windows.dll!MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(System.IntPtr unmanagedObj, System.IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, int argsTypeIndex, int actualArgsTypeIndex, string eventName, uint flags) + 0x28f bytes
[Appdomain Transition]
```

Comment: Not a real answer, so I'm putting this in the comments. But it seems you're not alone: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495242/silverlight-5-accessviolationexception, http://forums.silverlight.net/t/245247.aspx/1, ...

Comment: I'm still fighting with this one. Are you able reproduce this? I'm not able to make this happen outside of my project.

Comment: Are you using Telerik's controls? They have fixed one occurrence of this (I've been following some links, copying this info here).

Comment: I am not using telerik controls, didn't tried to create a test project,

Comment: @jv42: Have Telerik provided any info about the fix, what it required, or even the cause of this behavior?

Comment: @MichaelS I've followed the link from the first comment, here is the link to the Telerik forums: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/general-discussions/silverlight-5-issues-q3-sp1.aspx#1923425

Comment: Microsoft has apparently fixed an AccessViolation crash in the latest SL5 version: https://www.microsoft.com/getsilverlight/locale/en-us/html/Microsoft%20Silverlight%20Release%20History.htm#SL_5_1_10411

Answer (score 3):

I have found one source of the issue (I am not sure that it solved all these AccessViolationException issues), but my system is much more stable now.

Apparently the use of **Bureau Black Theme from the latest toolkit**, with combination of **TextBox**, caused this issue.

What I have done to solve it is to **recompile this theme without the Style of the TextBox** and the issue of AccessViolation has disappeared, at this stage we didn't do deep testing on the entire system, but this is solving an issue that I could repro rapidly so I assume that this might have fixed more issues like that.

Hope it helped someone.

Regards,

Lior

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've found a solution. Previously I had the overall app styles/theme set in the Mainpage.xaml file - and the theme rippled down to all child navigation pages at runtime. this was causing the problem somehow.

If I explictly set the style on a page by page basis - everything works!!

Thus: (using the BureauBlue toolkit theme)

```
xmlns:SystemColors="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Theming;     assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BureauBlue" 

<SystemColors:BureauBlueTheme>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
```

.
 .
 .

Answer (score 1):

The use of Bureau Blue also causes the same System.AccessViolationException when updating a property bound to a text box.

The work-around that worked for me was to copy the TextBox style from the Theme dll into a ResourceDictionary that is merged into the App.xaml resource dictionary.  Doing this avoided having to specify the theme on every view.

The themes I am using are from the April 2010 toolkit.  I don't know if a later toolkit release may have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is it is either a faulty runtime installation, or browser add-on or antivirus.

Troubleshoot it this way:

1. What does DrWatson logs show? Tess Ferrandez has a lot of information on how to read crash logs. Or post your crash log here.
2. Does it happen with different browsers?
3. Can you turn off any Add-Ons?
4. Does it happen on all computers?
5. Does your app use any COM automation or PInvoke?

Comment: This error reaccour on different computers (more than 2)
and on different browsers.

Comment: I have also attached screen shot to the qustion, but this is what i get as exception.
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  InnerException:

Comment: Have a look at this ContentManagerSilverlight!ContentManagerSilverlight.TextPropertyPanel.set_ItemDetails Perhaps it is cross-thread access.

Comment: No, it is happenning from the Main thread of the application (i have doubled checked it from my Visual Studio)