# Catastrophic failure when upgrading to Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I just updated my silverlight browser plugin to v5 and realized that my fully functional silverlight 4 app didn't run at all. That is strange because the silverlight 5 plugin should be complete backward compatible right? I then downloaded the Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 as well as the Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime for Windows (32 bit) to start debugging.

Now I have digged into the problem and realized that it is several Controls wrapped in a Canvas that causes the problem, i.e the following throws a Catastrophic Failure in VS2010:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Logo.SilverlightControl2"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 mc:Ignorable="d"
 d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
     <Canvas >
         <TextBlock Canvas.Left="120" Canvas.Top="110" Height="23" Name="TextBlock1" Text="TextBlock" />
     </Canvas>
 </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

There must be something I am missing, can anyone maybe have a clue of what is going on?

**Update:**
It seems I cannot view a single Silverlight 5 app in the [Silverlight showcase](http://www.silverlight.net/showcase). Each and everyone of them just shows a blank white area. Maybe there is something wrong with my plugin installation?

Comment: There are some compatibility issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495242/silverlight-5-accessviolationexception and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743921/upgrade-from-silverlight-4-to-silverlight-5-causing-accessviolationexception for instance. But if you can't see any SL5 app, you must have a local error.

Answer (score 0):

This exception can be caused also by invoking

```
Application.CheckAndDownloadUpdateAsync()
```

when a xap file on a server is not accessable.